# Select last 24 hours data from SQL Server in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have two columns in my table, `Date` and `Total_Amount`. I need to display the data from the last 24 hours, and sum the result and show that sum in a textbox using VB.NET.

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "Select Sum(Total_Amount) as Total_AmountSum from Table_10"

Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim table As New DataTable()
adapter.Fill(table)

If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
    TextBox1.Text = table.Rows(0)("Total_AmountSum").ToString()
End If
```

Comment: What is the question? Did you tried `WHERE`?

Comment: If you're using **SQL Server** - please use the `sql-server` tag - not `sql` and `server` separately - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **[DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)** here

Try this

**For last 24 hours**

```
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "Select Sum(CASE WHEN [Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN Total_Amount END) As Total_AmountSum from Table_10"
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = table.Rows(0)("Total_AmountSum").ToString()
    End If
```

**For last 1 month**

```
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "Select Sum(CASE WHEN [Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN Total_Amount END) As Total_AmountSum from Table_10"
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = table.Rows(0)("Total_AmountSum").ToString()
    End If
```

**For last 1 week**

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "Select Sum(CASE WHEN [Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(ww, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN Total_Amount END) As Total_AmountSum from Table_10"
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim table As New DataTable()
adapter.Fill(table)
If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
    TextBox1.Text = table.Rows(0)("Total_AmountSum").ToString()
End If
```

Comment: dear last month coding not working i have make 31 rows in the table but it also get the record of the last 31 column

Comment: dear i need one more query for weekly data please

Comment: @Sattar5 post a new question

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use below query:

```
Select Sum(Total_Amount) as Total_AmountSum from Table_10
WHERE   [Date]>= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: No Thing Display in Textbox